# List files which have 'c' as second letter (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ls

How can I do that? Do I have to use regular expressions?

To clarify, let's say I have the following files in a directory: *abc.sh acb.sh example.c bob.php* - and I want to list the ones which has 'c' as second letter (i.e. *acb.sh*).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working in the shell

```
ls ?c*
```

is all that it takes.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
ls ?c*
```

I guess it will do.. question mark stands for single character.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | grep "^.c"
```

Also works, here ^ indicates beginning of line, so ^. says match any single character at beginning and then match c.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `find` command:

```
find ./ -name "?c*.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls . | grep '^.c'
```

where `.` represents the present working directory

or

```
find / -type d -exec grep '^.c' {};
```

or

```
find / -type d | grep '^.c'
```